# NewPtrClear is deprecated

Tags: c, objective-c, pointers, struct

I'm converting some procedural C code to Objective-C using xCode v12.5. In C I made extensive use of complex structures where I would clear memory for a pointer then assign the structure to the pointer. Example...

```
        WinPeek  wData = nil; //pointer to a structure called WinRecord
        Ptr      wStorage;
        wStorage = NewPtrClear(sizeof(WinRecord));
        wData = (WinPeek)wStorage;
```

The above code works in xCode v12.5 since you can mix C and Objective-C however NewPtrClear generates a warning that it is deprecated. Does the combination of malloc and memset accomplish the same thing as NewPtrClear?

```
        wStorage = malloc(sizeof(WinRecord));
        memset(wStorage, 0, sizeof(WinRecord));
        wData = (WinPeek)wStorage;
```

assuming that malloc and memset accomplish the task, is there a way to accomplish this directly in objective-c

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69803350/edit) when you want to update it.

Comment: Do you mean "it compiles" or "it works"? Because what you are doing looks a lot like Carbon to me which should have stopped working years ago.

Comment: Carbon is a set of APIs that worked with the procedural C language. I am now working in Cocoa in a combination of Objective C, Swift and some procedural C mixed. One of the few Carbon APIs still in the code was NewPtrClr which Xcode was happy to compile for use in Catalina, Big Sur and Monterey with the admonition that it is Deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same thing, but you could also just use `calloc(1, sizeof(WinRecord))` to do the allocate and clear in one step.

Comment: Thanks Scott, calloc produces the same result as the malloc, memset combination. In both cases, the struct, which is a combination of types (Boolean, int, float, strings, even arrarys of type int) are all initialized to zero or nil.